# emscripten: "function requested to be exported, but not implemented"

Tags: javascript, c, r, emscripten

There is a function in `R` called `pf`, the source is [here](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/nmath/pf.c#L28).

I'm trying to get this function converted to JavaScript with emscripten. I'm invoking like this:

```
emcc -s EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS="['pf']" nmath/pf.c \
-Ignuwin32/fixed/h/ \
-I/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.1.1/include/ \
-I/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.1.1/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/include/
```

I get the warning:

```
WARNING  root: function requested to be exported, but not implemented: "pf"
```

And, no hint of `pf` in the output js. Why is this function "not implemented" according to emcc?

Edit (according to zakki's answer it should be `_pf` as in `-s EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS="['_pf']"` but the problem persists):

There is a prior warning about absolute include paths. But, I'm assuming that it can be ignored? Maybe it is crucial though:

```
emcc -s EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS="['_pf']" nmath/pf.c -Ignuwin32/fixed/h/ -I/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.1.1/include/ -I/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.1.1/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/include/

WARNING  root: -I or -L of an absolute path "-I/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.1.1/include/" encountered. If this is to a local system header/library, it may cause problems (local system files make sense for compiling natively on your system, but not necessarily to JavaScript). Pass '-Wno-warn-absolute-paths' to emcc to hide this warning.
WARNING  root: function requested to be exported, but not implemented: "_pf"
```

If I try the other method, adding `EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE`, as described [here](http://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/getting_started/FAQ.html#why-do-functions-in-my-c-c-source-code-vanish-when-i-compile-to-javascript-and-or-i-get-no-functions-to-process), I get:

```
emcc nmath/pf.c -Ignuwin32/fixed/h/ -I/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.1.1/include/ -I/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.1.1/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/include/  

WARNING  root: -I or -L of an absolute path "-I/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.1.1/include/" encountered. If this is to a local system header/library, it may cause problems (local system files make sense for compiling natively on your system, but not necessarily to JavaScript). Pass '-Wno-warn-absolute-paths' to emcc to hide this warning.
nmath/pf.c:28:28: error: expected ';' after top level declarator
double EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE pf(double x, double df1, double df2, int lower_tail, int log_p)
                           ^
                           ;
1 error generated.
ERROR    root: compiler frontend failed to generate LLVM bitcode, halting
```

Answer (score 5):

Add '_' to function name.

`-s EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS="['_pf']"`

Comment: Still: `WARNING  root: function requested to be exported, but not implemented: "_pf"`

Comment: Good call, though, definitely should be `_pf`

Comment: Is `_Rf_pf` OK? https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/07ac1e21db175ac877530a5d0105906911e56c18/src/include/Rmath.h0.in#L272

Comment: oh, I think we might be getting somewhere ... how did you figure that out @zakki

Comment: still, not sure if it will work:

warning: unresolved symbol: Rf_pbeta
warning: unresolved symbol: Rf_pchisq
warning: unresolved symbol: R_NaN
warning: unresolved symbol: R_NegInf
warning: unresolved symbol: R_PosInf

Comment: I used github search https://github.com/wch/r-source/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=define+pf&type=Code

Comment: Unless you link mlutils.c, pchisq.c and ... by hand, `emconfigure` would help   http://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/compiling/Building-Projects.html